# The opening of the layouts as conditional status in the activity

Tags: android

I have two layouts. one is to show in main activity if we have internet connection. and the other one is also to show in the same activity if we have not internet connection.

I want when I launch the program and there is internet connection then I see `activity_main.xml` layout. and also I want when I launch the program and there is not internet connection then I see `error.xml` layout.

But when I run the program It can not do the top description well.please do not say for me that I do not know concepts android and please help me to solve this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    ImageView imageView1,imageView2,imageView3;
    Drawable drawable0,drawable1,drawable2;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle s){

        if(isConnected()==false){
            super.onCreate(s);
            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            setContentView(R.layout.error);
        }
        else if(isConnected()==true){
super.onCreate(s);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(88,255,114));
            imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            drawable0 = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image.jpg");
            drawable1 = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image2.jpg");
            drawable2 = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image4.jpg");
            imageView1.setImageDrawable(drawable0);
            imageView2.setImageDrawable(drawable1);
            imageView3.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try{
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"");
            return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {

            return null;
        }
    }}
```

Comment: whats happen when u try to run???

Comment: the program stops and I get ' has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.'

Answer (score 0):

Your code fail because you call `findViewById` **before** calling `setContentView`. So `findViewById` return null and `imageView1.setImageDrawable(drawable0);` will lead to a `NullPointerException`.

ANd you are also doing networking operation on the main thread (in `LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)`). This is another reason for your code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code, as the friend pointed out.

Besides your approach is wrong. You should change the **fragments** layout

Create 2 different fragments, one with you main layout and other with your error. Add the fragments to you activity after the result of the connection test.

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
        activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

if ( isConnected )
{
    loadFragWithConnection;
} else {
    loadFragWithoutConnection;
}
```

Don't forget to ask for permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`